# T-Sql find duplicate row values

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure.

In that stored procedure, I want to find duplicate row values from a table, and calculate sum operation on these rows to the same table.

Let's say, I have a `CustomerSales` table;

```
ID  SalesRepresentative Customer  Quantity 
1   Michael             CustA        55     
2   Michael             CustA        10
```

and I need to turn table to...

```
ID  SalesRepresentative Customer  Quantity 
1   Michael             CustA        65     
2   Michael             CustA        0
```

When I find `SalesRepresentative` and `Customer` duplicates at the same time, I want to sum all `Quantity` values of  these rows and assign to the first row of a table, and others will be '0'.

Could you help me.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also: it's a store*D* procedure - as in **STORED** in SQL Server - it has nothing to do with a *store* ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To aggregate duplicates into **one row**:

```
SELECT min(ID) AS ID, SalesRepresentative, Customer
      ,sum(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM   CustomerSales 
GROUP  BY SalesRepresentative, Customer
ORDER  BY min(ID)
```

Or, if you actually want those **extra rows with `0`** as `Quantity` in the result:

```
SELECT ID, SalesRepresentative, Customer
      ,CASE 
          WHEN (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesRepresentative,Customer)) = 1
             THEN Quantity
          WHEN (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesRepresentative,Customer
                                   ORDER BY ID)) = 1 
             THEN sum(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesRepresentative,Customer)
          ELSE 0
       END AS Quantity
FROM   CustomerSales
ORDER  BY ID
```

This makes heavy use of [**window functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

Alternative version without window functions:

```
SELECT min(ID) AS ID, SalesRepresentative, Customer, sum(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM   CustomerSales 
GROUP  BY SalesRepresentative, Customer

UNION ALL 
SELECT ID, SalesRepresentative, Customer, 0 AS Quantity
FROM   CustomerSales c
GROUP  BY SalesRepresentative, Customer
LEFT   JOIN (
    SELECT min(ID) AS ID
    FROM   CustomerSales 
    GROUP  BY SalesRepresentative, Customer
   ) x ON (x.ID = c.ID)
WHERE  x.ID IS NULL
ORDER  BY ID
```

Comment: Yes, Something like this. I tried your solution,and make some changes, <br />   SELECT [SalesRep], [Customer]
      ,sum(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY [SalesRep], [Customer])
FROM   CustomerSales <br /> It works, except one thing. It sums same row values, but it does not make '0' the other rows. 
ORDER  BY ID, [SalesRep], [Customer]

Comment: @BertanULUSOY: Please consider the updated version of my answer.

Comment: Yes, It work absolutely. Second answer is great... Thanks a lot Erwin. OVER(PARTITION... is not a Cursor, isn't it?

Comment: @BertanULUSOY: That is the syntax of a window function. I added a link to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, this is the first time I use and realize that window function.